# Android wont add views to the scroll view dynamically

Tags: android, scrollview

Trying to add some views to the scrollview dynamically in a loop but there is  no effect or any sort of crash  I have atablelyout inside a scroll view and adding table row views in the loop

///loops runs 5 times

```
ScrollView parent = (ScrollView) root.getRootView()
                                .findViewById(R.id.scrolltbl);
                            View child = getLayoutInflater(
                                    savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.attditem, null);

                            String lecs = findint(tds.text());// attdTile
                            String leves = findint(leaves.text());
                            String abs = findint(absents.text());

                        ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.lecs))
                                    .setText(lecs);
                            ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.lvs))
                                    .setText(leves);
                            ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.abs))
                                    .setText(abs);
                            ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.crsname))
                            .setText(tTrs[f]);
                            Log.w("count","2d");
                            parent.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not add more than one view in scrollview. Use LinearLayout inside scrollView and content on this view. Finally add linearlayout in ScrollView